# tooltip of self content of input element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want when user hover above the input field the tooltip will be the input content, for example if I have

```
<input>hello world</input>
```

I want when user hover above this input he will see it's content, how can I achive that via html/css/js/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, you have the `input`:

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="showThis(this);">
```

the function content should be:

```
function showThis(me) {
    me.setAttribute('title', me.value);
}
```